# Using 2 levels avobe column in union subquery

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very complicated query which involves a subquery and this subquery usas an union as the table. I want to use a column from the first level (a field before the subquery) as part of the where clausule in the union. Like this:

```
SELECT 
    type, 
    registered_number - (
        SELECT 
            MAX(last)
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                MAX(b) as last
            FROM 
                x
            WHERE  
                a = type 
            UNION ALL 
            SELECT 
                MAX(b) as last
            FROM 
                y
            WHERE 
                a = type
        ) as last_table
    ) as last
FROM `x`;
```

**Sample data**

Table X

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 26 |
| 3 | 27 |

TABLE Y

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 24 |
| 3 | 31 |

TABLE s

| id | type | registered_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 3 | 9 |

EXPECTED RESULT

| type | last |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 |
| 2 | 18 |
| 3 | 22 |

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing a union of the `x` and `y` tables first, then join `s` to an aggregate of the union subquery.

```sql
SELECT s.type, t.b AS last
FROM s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a, MAX(b) AS b
    FROM
    (
        SELECT a, b FROM x
        UNION ALL
        SELECT a, b FROM y
    ) t
    GROUP BY a
) t
    ON t.a = s.type
ORDER BY s.type;
```

Comment: I need to rest that value to another column in order to get the desired total

Comment: My answer should generate the output you expect.  Not sure what else you expect.